# problem with css and background header

Tags: html, css

How i Can align the nav.png to the site??
I design this background called nav.png
And I need align to the rest of the site
the site is http://www.newprincess.cl/WebPrueba
Explain on this image 
http://imageshack.us/f/10/imageslide.jpg/

This is a problem with css or something????

Please need help
Very thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to set to your `<div id="nav">` following:

```
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: center;
```

and crop your background image from the left a little :)

Answer (score 0):

This image should be 980px, same width as #center. And no offense, your page contains so many errors, you might as well do some reconstuction.